# Trying to create a custom search button in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to set up a custom search for an Excel spreadsheet that I use daily.  It's a new sheet that is sent to me each day, and it's huge.  I need to find specific rows to gather information.  What I'm trying to achieve is to create a button on my toolbar that pops up a user input box where I can enter a number, which will then be used for conditional formatting, that will look for that number in a specific column (Column C) and when it finds any instances of that number in that column it will highlight the entire row (or most of it at least), and also take me to the first instance of the number in that column. 
I think a Macro is the way to go here, but my VBA coding skills are lacking.

I've managed to get the conditional formatting to work (sort of) where I can enter a number into a cell, and it will highlight 6 of the 15 columns in my spreadsheet for each row which contains that number in column C.  I'm happy with that part.
I have no idea how to create the user input box though, and make the input interact with my conditional formatting. So that's where I'm stuck.

I've been searching on Google for a couple of hours, but I haven't come up with anything that works yet.

I'm not expecting anyone to create the macro for me, but some advice on how to find the information I'm after would be appreciated.

Comment: This [link](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html) covers the basics of user form creation so I'd suggest starting with that, then have a crack at creating a sub that the button calls and come back with the attempt here - we can work with your code (however bad your first try is) to help you understand what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this method.. personally. Coz no macro needed.. but still do the job.

Idea : 1. enter search term in C2. 2. filter the column, that had been fed with this formula : " use search in a cell, display 1 if found. "

Implementation :

Assuming the search column/data starts at A2, do :

`B2  ->  =IFERROR(IF(SEARCH($C$1,A2),1,0),"")`

and drag downwards.

Set up a filter in column B header. Reserve cell C1 as the "Search" box.

To use.. just enter the search term in C1, then filter/refresh filter (for 1) in column B.

Done.

Hope it helps..

p/s : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is the shortcut to "Reapply filter".

Comment: Going through that, it doesn't look like it will do what i need.  I have a Macro right now that uses a specific cell in the spreadsheet itself (not my preferred option but it will do, since I'm putting that cell in the frozen header row).  This is the macro code I'm using at the moment.  it's a work in progress.


For some reason though, it's often highlighting the row above the rows that actually contain my value.  No idea why that is happening yet.

Comment: I tried to post my code, but it turns out so messy it's very hard to read.

Comment: try highlighting it (the code) the press ctrl+k to format it as a code.

Comment: I've got it sorted out now.  I ended up doing the sub different and it's working for me.  Thanks for the help :)